# Sql server query to LINQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to change the following sql query to linq

```
select top(1) CableCode 
from (SELECT top(10) (cablecode) 
      FROM Cables 
      WHERE CableCode>=20704 
      ORDER BY CableCode) as a 
order by CableCode desc
```

Comment: I'll say that in LINQ it is nearly equal, so you could try to write it.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried to translate that sql to LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

The query you asked, just to show that it's nearly equal. I've splitted it in three parts to make it clear how it works

```
var innerQuery = (from x in db.Cables
                  where x.CableCode >= 20704
                  orderby x.CableCode
                  select x.CableCode).Take(10);

var outerQuery = (from x in innerQuery
                  orderby x descending
                  select x); // Useless: .Take(1);

int? singleElement = outerQuery.FirstOrDefault(); // Instead of TOP(1)
```

Note that instead of the `.Take(1)` (equivalent to the `TOP(1)`), that would have returned an `IEnumerable<>`, I used directly the `FirstOrDefault()`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var result = (from c in (db.Cables.Where(x => x.CableCode >= 20704)
                               .OrderBy(x => x.CableCode).Take(10)) 
                 orderby c.CableCode descending select c.CableCode).FirstOrDefault();
```